# whenever => cron job not accessing my model/database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am using whenever gem to create a cron job. This cron job needs to run a helper method on my rails app at a regular interval. This helper method checks every instance of my model and decides to update it or not.

/app/helpers/auctions_helper.rb:

```
module AuctionsHelper

  def self.checkForExpiredAuction
    # method to update each auction that has expired
    puts "There are currently #{Auction.count} auctions."

    @auctions = Auction.all
    @auctions.each do |auction|
      if auction.end_time > Time.now.utc
        auction.price = 1000000
        auction.save
        puts "just updated #{auction.product} auction"
      end
    end
    puts "just updated any auctions that had expired"
  end
end
```

schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
every 1.minute do
  runner "AuctionsHelper.checkForExpiredAuction"
end
```

which creates the following cronjob:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: bestBay
            * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/bestbay && script/rails runner -e production '\''AuctionsHelper.checkForExpiredAuction'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
#    End Whenever generated tasks for: bestBay
```

The problem I'm having is that the helper method can't access the table 'auctions'. From my cron_log.log:

```
Could not find table 'auctions' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

This doesn't seem to be a problem with the helper method itself. If I run from terminal:

```
rails runner AuctionsHelper.checkForExpiredAuction
```

I get a nice set of outputs from my puts messages. So why can't my cronjob access my model/table?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?  If you're on 3.x then you should use the `task` option instead of `runnner`, which should result in a command wrapped in `bundle exec <command>` -- bundler ensures that your full and normal rails environment (and gems, etc.) are loaded.

Comment: from DOCS: doesn't runner already do this:
"The default job types that ship with Whenever are defined like so:
...
job_type :runner,  "cd :path && script/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"
...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem was that cron wasn't spooling up the same environment variables as when I just opened a shell prompt. I also had a .rvm file that was loading my ruby environment and getset every time I cd'd into the main application directory. I finally had to do this:

```
# set the cron log location
set :output, {:error => '/home/jason/bestbay/log/cron_error.log', :standard => '/home/jason/bestbay/log/cron_status.log'}
set :job_template, "bash -i -c ':job'"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

every 1.minute do
  #command "echo $PATH"                             # confirm shell variable PATH was loaded
  #command "cd #{path}"                             # this is not needed
  #command "pwd"                                    # visualize current directory
  #command "rvm current"                            # visualized default ruby version and gemset
  command "rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@cmucourse"       # set desired gemest
  #command "rvm current"                            # visualize proper gemset load

  runner "AuctionsHelper.checkForExpiredAuction", :environment => 'development' # run method
end
```

I'm including the commented out commands because they really helped me visualize what was happening when cron ran.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the runner will run in `RAILS_ENV=development` while the cron line is wired to run on "production" environment.

Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails runner AuctionsHelper.checkForExpiredAuction
```

If you get the same error, then that is the problem

For testing, point your production environment to your development, in database.yml

```
production:
  development
```

Answer (score 0):

`whatever` defaults to production and will by default look for a production database. To change this behaviour you can update the crontab and set it to development as such:

```sh
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

Hope this saves someone a bit of time as it had me for a while.